# How to show and hide multiple html selects with dynamic variable properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with options, let's call it Car Brands:

```
<select id="car-brands">
    <option value="noselection">Car Brand</option>
    <option value="toyota">TOYOTA</option>
    <option value="lexus">LEXUS</option>
</select>
```

And I have another 2 selects, let's call them car models:

```
<select id="car-models-toyota" style="display:none;">
    <option value="noselection">Car Model</option>
    <option value="toyota">AVENSIS</option>
    <option value="lexus">CAMRY</option>
</select>
<select id="car-models-lexus" style="display:none;">
    <option value="noselection">Car Model</option>
    <option value="toyota">AVENSIS</option>
    <option value="lexus">CAMRY</option>
</select>
```

I hide them, so when user selecting TOYOTA or LEXUS in first select, Car Models will show up by their theme:

```
$('#car-brands').change(function() {
    const brand = $(this).val();
    $(`#car-models-${brand}`).show();
});
```

And it's working, car models selects show up, but I can't understand how can I hide another with this dynamic variable?

I mean I select TOYOTA and `#car-models-toyota select` shows up, select LEXUS and `#car-models-lexus select` shows up, but when it shows up `toyota select` should be hidden.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this **by making all `select` elements hidden first in each first `select`, `change` event, and then shown the desired on**e by your provided code. So all you have to do is to select all selects (except the brand select) with `$('select').not('#car-brands')` then use [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) to make all of them hidden.

So this should be something like this:

```js
$('#car-brands').change(function() {
    const brand = $(this).val();
    $('select').not('#car-brands').hide();
    $(`#car-models-${brand}`).show();
});
```

Comment: Much better that Edit :)